# Are chrome apps code visible to the users?

Tags: html, google-chrome-app

I was thinking about writing a chrome app in html5. This would be an app on the desktop for the user to use, independent of the internet. However, the concern is what if there are algorithms that I don't want the user to see or copy? I would just want to grant the user the ability to apply it.

Is it impossible to hide the app code that you wouldn't want the user to copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to hide your code. You can obfuscate and minimize it, but that is about it.

If you have proprietary algorithms you're protective of, you can always leave them on a server and use XHR to execute them there. Or you could use native client to have a portion of your app written in C and compiled to a low level intermediate language (portable NaCl, which is preferred), or machine code (NaCl).

Note all native apps have this problem; machine code can also be reverse engineered. Its just easier with HTML / javascript.